# How do I dynamically import locales in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm attempting to dynamically import locales in an Angular 9 (monorepo-based) app. I'm doing something like the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class LocaleService {
    ...

    private capitalize(str: string): string {
        return str.charAt[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    registerLocales() {
        for (const lang of ['de', 'fr', 'es']) {
            const basePkg = `locale${this.capitalize(lang)}`;
            const extraPkg = basePkg + 'Extra';

            const base = import(`@angular/common/locales/${lang}`).then(m => m[basePkg]);
            const extra = import(`@angular/common/locales/extra/${lang}`).then(m => m[extraPkg]);

            registerLocaleData(base, extra);
        }
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';
import localeEs from '@angular/common/locales/es';
import localeEsExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/es';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import localeFrExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/fr';

@Injectable()
export class LocaleService {
    ...

    registerLocales() {
        registerLocaleData(localeDe, localeDeExtra);
        registerLocaleData(localeEs, localeEsExtra);
        registerLocaleData(localeFr, localeFrExtra);
    }
}
```

Within this code even executing, I'm getting a boatload of errors caused by the imports of the form:

> WARNING in
>   /home/me/somerepo/node_modules/@angular/common/locales/zu.d.ts Module
>   build failed (from
>   /home/me/somerepo/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
>   Error:
>   /home/me/somerepo/node_modules/@angular/common/locales/zu.d.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Commenting out the imports and call to `registerLocaleData` eliminates the error. What on earth am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I not full read it, but I think this link can help you: https://indepth.dev/dynamic-import-of-locales-in-angular/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [excellent article](https://indepth.dev/dynamic-import-of-locales-in-angular/) mentioned by Eliseo's comment has the answer. Typescript's `import` function is not an ordinary function call. In short, what's happening here is that import tells Webpack to create chunks for *everything* that matches the pattern in the argument. This is a problem, because the pattern matches all of the `.d.ts` files in the locales directory, while we actually only want the `.js` files. The solution is to use Webpack's "[magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments)". The following is enough to get everything loading properly:

```
const base = import(
  /* webpackExclude: /\.d\.ts$/ */
  `@angular/common/locales/${key}`).then(m => m[basePkg]);

const extra = import(
  /* webpackExclude: /\.d\.ts$/ */
  `@angular/common/locales/extra/${key}`).then(m => m[extraPkg]);
```

But... there are a couple of problems.

1. *Every* locale is turned into a chunk. That creates over 1,000 chunks. Ouch.
2. The chunks are just given numbers as names.

Magic comments to the rescue again:

```
const base = import(
  /* webpackExclude: /\.d\.ts$/ */
  /* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */
  /* webpackChunkName: "i18n-base" */
  `@angular/common/locales/${key}`).then(m => m[basePkg]);

const extra = import(
  /* webpackExclude: /\.d\.ts$/ */
  /* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */
  /* webpackChunkName: "i18n-extra" */
  `@angular/common/locales/extra/${key}`).then(m => m[extraPkg]);
```

This gets closer, creating two chunks instead of thousands, but they're *big*. If we know what locales we're interested in, we can do a lot better. Here's the final version:

```
const base = import(
  /* webpackInclude: /^(de|en|es|fr|it|nl|no|pl|pt-BR|pt|fi|sv|ko|ru|zh|zh-Hans|zh-Hant|ja)\.js/ */
  /* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */
  /* webpackChunkName: "i18n-base" */
  `@angular/common/locales/${key}`).then(m => m[basePkg]);

const extra = import(
  /* webpackInclude: /^(de|en|es|fr|it|nl|no|pl|pt-BR|pt|fi|sv|ko|ru|zh|zh-Hans|zh-Hant|ja)\.js/ */
  /* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */
  /* webpackChunkName: "i18n-extra" */
  `@angular/common/locales/extra/${key}`).then(m => m[extraPkg]);
```

This changes the logic from specifying which files to ignore to specifying which files to load. It results in chunks of around 100Kb instead of 6Mb.

Comment: There is an issue with the solution, the files are named i18n-extra and i18n-base without the hash. Any alternatives for adding the hash? https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4807#issuecomment-554734522

Comment: A follow up to this - what if the locale files are my own (not from angular lib) and not referenced anywhere else in the application? I get: Module build failed (from ...@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js): Error: ...\i18n\lib-forms-messages.cn.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property." If I run typescript compile myself (tsc), it shows that file in the list. But it seems that angular+webpack elides them out (tree shakes them) before bundling.

Comment: While this does work, please note that some unused modules might be included. For example, if you use the regex `/(de)\.js/`, `de.js` and `kde.js` are included. In my current project with 16 languages, I have 16 unused modules.

Comment: Found the issue. You need to add a `^` at the start of the regex: `/* webpackInclude: /^(de|en|es|fr|it|nl|no|pl|pt-BR|pt|fi|sv|ko|ru|zh|zh-Hans|zh-Hant|ja)\.js/ */`
Could you update your answer?

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve a particular file on runtime (over network) using dynamic imports? I don't want all these file to become a part of the main bundle.

Comment: how do you enable these magic comments? My angular devs server just tells me `TS2304: Cannot find name 'key'` etc.

Comment: This is great stuff. `ng serve` and `ng build` are now ~ 50% faster than before. Thanks for that! Sadly we cannot really tell which languages we need.

Small addition, if you import ``@angular/common/locales/${key}.mjs``, the chunk is much smaller!

Answer (score 6):

I took a different approach and decided to use [@ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) to manage the translations and 
the [@ngx-translate/http-loader](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader) to dynamically load the translations from a JSON file on app load. 
This will keep the build size smaller because it doesn't build/bundle the translations. It just copies over the translated json files as assets

The folder structure looks like this:

```
src
├── app
│   ├── ...
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   └── app.modules.ts
├── environments
│   └── environment.ts
└── i18l
    ├── en-us.json
    ├── es.json
    └── ...
```

Add the **src/i18l/** directory to `assets` in **angular.json**:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/i18l" // <-- add this
            ]
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Setup the translation module in **app.module.ts**

```js
// other imports 
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory (http: HttpClient) {
  // this tells the translation service what path to fetch the translation from
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'i18l/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    // other imports
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I like to keep a list of available translations in my **environments/enviornment.ts** file:

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  availableTranslations: [
    'en-us',
    'es'
  ]
};
```

Then you need to select and load the translation at some point on app load. For simplicity, this is an example in
**app.component.ts**

```js
// other imports
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  localeForm: FormGroup;
  locales: string[];
  translationLoaded: boolean = false;

  constructor (
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.locales = environment.availableTranslations.slice(); //slice to create a copy
    // just a basic form for the user to select a translation
    this.localeForm = new FormGroup({
      locale: new FormControl('en-us', {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }

  async submitForm (): void {
    // await the http request for the translation file
    await this.translateService.use(this.localeForm.value.locale).toPromise();
    this.translationLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

Create a basic form for the user to select the translation in **app.component.html**

```html
<!-- if we have loaded a translation, display the app -->
<ng-container *ngIf="translationLoaded">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-container>

<!-- if we haven't loaded the translation, show the translation picker -->
<ng-container *ngIf="!translationLoaded">
  You need to select a language

  <form [formGroup]="localeForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <label for="locale">Select a Language</label>
    <select name="locale" id="locale" formControlName="locale">
      <option *ngFor="let loc of locales" id="{{loc}}" value="{{loc}}">
        {{loc}}
      </option>
    </select>

    <label for="useLocale">Use Language</label>
    <button name="useLocale" type="submit" [disabled]="!localeForm.valid">Select</button>
  </form>

</ng-container>
```

Set up the translation form and app initialization however you would like. That is just a simple example. Then you can follow the [documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive) on how to use the translation service throughout your app.

I've never worked with `@angular/common/locale`. I realize this may not be an exact fix for the webpack issue. Hopefully it could help others if they are looking for translation solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get my specific languages registered for angular's pipe with this

```js
try {
  // register locale for pipes
  const localeModule = await
  import (
    /* webpackInclude: /\b(en|en-GB|fr|de|ru|sv|lt|it|es|ja|sk|pl|ca|nl|tr)\.mjs/ */
    `/node_modules/@angular/common/locales/${locale}`
  );
  registerLocaleData(localeModule.default);
} catch {
  console.warn('Translation file error found for Angular pipes.');
}
```

I tried to do the start of string regex symbol `^` to start the explicit word match but it wouldn't go through for some reason. So I tried the word boundary regex symbol `\b` and it seems to work. If you want to eliminate the other nested folders you'll probably have to add in a `/* webpackExclude: /folder\/.*\.mjs/ */`

Comment: Thnx Alisha, you just save my time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a combination of all of the above but kept getting locale not loaded so I now have a running version, more or less like with these changes:

*The file names (except for main.ts) are mostly for the example's sake*

In `tsconfig.json` I changed module to `esnext`

```
        "module": "esnext",
```

Added a function to dynamically import locales in`src/app/services/locale.service.ts` (angular 14 verified)

```
export const localesList = ['en', 'en_US', 'et'];
export const initializeLocales = async (): Promise<Promise<void[]>> => {
    return Promise.all(
        localesList.map(async (locale) => {
            await import(
                /* webpackInclude: /(en|en_US|et)\.mjs$/ */
                `/node_modules/@angular/common/locales/${locale}`
            )
                .then((module) => {
                    registerLocaleData(module.default);
                })
                .catch(() => null);
        })
    );
};
```

In `main.ts` (how I avoided the locales not being loaded)

```
initializeLocales().then(() => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

In `app.module.ts` we load the providers:

```
    providers: [
    {
        provide: LOCALE_ID,
        deps: [LocaleService],
        useFactory: (localeService: LocaleService): string => localeService.getLocale(),
    },
],
```

And a locale service where to store what locale is the current one, `src/app/services/locale.service.ts`

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LocaleService {
    public locale: string | null;

    getLocale(): string {
          //retrieve it from localstorage or somewhere else
        return this.locale as string;
    }

    setLocale(locale: string): void {
        // additionally set it in localStorage or a cookie or something
        this.locale = locale;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My consolidated solution from serveral answers here is

Provider in app.module.ts

```
{
  provide: LOCALE_ID,
  useValue: navigator.language
}
```

And then in the constructor of my app.component.ts

```
constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {
 import(
    /* webpackInclude: /(.*)\.js$/ */
    `@angular/common/locales/${locale.substring(0, 2)}.js`
  ).then(module => registerLocaleData(module.default))
}
```

and then hope angular has an locale for each of my customer since this solution has no fallbak