# Webpack dynamic/lazy import chunk location

Tags: angular, webpack

Is there a way to specify webpack chunk paths? I am using Angular 9. I followed the instructions in [How do I dynamically import locales in Angular 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035621/how-do-i-dynamically-import-locales-in-angular-9) but I am trying to load all the locales so I end up with thousands of files. This is OK as most people are not going to use the files so they are never loaded unless someone picks the locale and if they do pick one, it loads just a small file.

My problem is that all of these chunks are generated in the same folder making it more difficult to manage. I would like to have all of chunked locale files go to a subfolder called locales. Does anyone know how this could be done? I couldn't find any additional [magic comment](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) to do this.

```
  private localeInitializer(localeId: string): Observable<any> {
    return from(import(
      /* webpackExclude: /\.d\.ts$/ */
      `@angular/common/locales/${localeId}.js`
    ).then(module => registerLocaleData(module.default)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the following:

```
/* webpackExclude: /\.d\.ts$/, webpackMode: "lazy", webpackChunkName: "locale-[request]" */
```

I wonder if you can use `/folder-name/` before the `webpackChunkName`?

If the above doesn't work, you'd have to use some sort of build task to move them out (like Gulp). You can prefix your JavaScript file names (see above how I prefix `locale-`) and just find all files by a glob then move them to a folder.

https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments

Looking at the webpack docs they do not have a magic comment for splitting up into a folder.